# Partially skip sections with Google Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm generating a javascript on the server like and would like to run Google Clousure Compiler to be ran on the php source code of the script.

```
var jsvar = <?=$var ? true : false ?>;
```

Just wandering if there is any way in telling the compiler to skip optimazation of ? Like a regexp skip:

```
/<\?=.*?\?>/
```

Best regards,

Niclas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that my code is much easier to maintain when I separate my client-side JavaScript from my server-side logic. Now I write my scripts such that my server-side processing emits initialization variables.

Example - Server Side:

```
<?php echo 'var mynamespace = {}; mynamespace.jsvar = "' . $var . '";'; ?>
```

And in my client-side javascript:

```
var mynamespace = window['mynamespace'] || {};
function MyFunction() {
  alert(mynamespace['jsvar']);
}
MyFunction();
```

Using this style, my client-side javascript compiles easily with Closure-compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
var jsvar = eval("<?=$var ? true : false ?>");
```

The compiler won't touch the contents of the string.