# Google Closure Compiler Parse Error

Tags: google-closure-compiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partially skip sections with Google Closure Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449195/partially-skip-sections-with-google-closure-compiler)

I get the following error from the compiler:

```
Number of errors: 2

JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. syntax error at line 17 character 18
window.location = <?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>"/";
                  ^
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. syntax error at line 17 character 47
window.location = <?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>"/";
                                               ^
```

It doesn't seem to like the (php) syntax. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolated the code in a string:

```
window.location = eval("<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>") + "/";
```

this is a similar problem to:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/UsingConditionalCommentWithClosureCompiler

Comment: Having forgotten everything I know about PHP you might want to use single quotes.