# Google closure compiler + Django template tags

Tags: django, google-closure-compiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partially skip sections with Google Closure Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449195/partially-skip-sections-with-google-closure-compiler)

I'm trying to use the closure compiler at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home to compress some JS. But it's failing because I have Django template tags in my javascript such as:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

and:

```
{{ csrf_token }}
```

Closure compiler says my syntax is incorrect. Is there any way to tell the compiler to ignore the template tags?

Comment: How are you using those tags? Are you planning to serve your compressed JS via the template engine?

Comment: Yes, my js is directly in my template files. I have certain sections of the code that I only want served to authenticated users. I also have a form that is dynamically inserted via js, so I need to pass the csrf_token to the js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the same techniques as for [IE Conditional Comments](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/UsingConditionalCommentWithClosureCompiler) or for [PHP Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449195/partially-skip-sections-with-google-closure-compiler/).