# Closure Compiler Advanced and Server-side injected Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

```
myVariable = "<%=myVar%>"
if ( myVariable == "Y" )  doSomething;
else doSoemthingElse;
```

I'm modifying code to be compilable in Advanced Mode.  Modifying Javascript using JSP/ASP/PHP/etc to inject variables is fairly common.
The methods I can think of for dealing with this involve using:

global variables

```
myVariable = window["myVariable"];
```

eval

```
myVariable = eval('"<%=myVar%>"');
```

replace using pre/post-processing script,

passing as function variables

```
function exposedFunction(myVariable){/* stuff */}
```

or passing an object and accessing properties by name

It'd be great if there were some way to annotate a variable as an unknown variable, even though it is defined as a string, or to trick the compiler into thinking so.

Maybe a better approach would be to create a pre/post-processing script for embedded Javascript that handles all these things?

EDIT:
It can be tedious searching out inlined variables or even worse more complicated <% %> snippets embedded in inline scripts and onclick events in html tags.

What would be the best recommended approach?
**I'd like to be able to** inline the <%=myVar%> string if possible, so that the output becomes

```
if("<%=myVar%>"=="Y")doSomething;else doSoemthingElse
```

But if not possible, would it be recommended to create a pre/post-build tool, just use global variables, use functions, or just treat it as situational?

Google themselves seem to inject inline variables into their inline Javascript some places.
Perhaps they have a pre/post-build tool?

What are some of the main considerations I should consider when choosing an approach?  I can only think of time/effort investment.
Is this just a case of trying too hard to optimize; should I just extract the <%%> things and put them in global variables?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct question here. Also, the problem you are having is not obvious - you have provided examples of several possible techniques but not mentioned why they do not work for you.

Comment: I updated with an edit

Comment: Note: I would settle for an automated pre/post-processing tool that implements most of what's needed.  It would effectively remove the time/effort investment.

Comment: You'll have better results if you approach the problem differently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449195/partially-skip-sections-with-google-closure-compiler/10462264#10462264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If used directly in a string <%...%>, you have to worry about whether the compiler will consider them constants:

"<%X%>" === "<%Y%>"

Will evaluated at compile time. Similiarly,  "if ('<%Foo%>') ..." is equivalent to "if (true) ...", so in general it is unwise to use them the substitutions directly.

Pre-processing the code to so that they substitutions are replaced in way that is safe for the compilation, seems reasonable:

"" + eval('"<%X%>"') + ""

But is tricky if you use source maps.