# Google Closure Compiler: apply compilation options on part of the input file

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I am using Closure Compiler to minify and obfuscate my JS files. But, can I modify the source code to control applying compilation options on part of the file rather than the whole file?

e.g For "foldConstants" option, can I apply it on part of the constants in the file instead of all of them?

Any insights would be appreciated here :)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449195/partially-skip-sections-with-google-closure-compiler

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported activity.